# How to remove the format of a selected text?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my custom WYSIWYG editor.

### This is how it works:

Select a text and click on a button. The text will be formatted. Unselect the same text and select it again. Now click again on the same button to remove the format.

### This is how it does NOT work:

Select a text and click on a button. The text will be formatted. Now click again on the same button to remove the format.

I assume, that it probably doesn't work, because I am inserting an element inside the parent element. So at this moment, this element is not selected. With `selectedText?.selectNode(node)` I have tried to select the correct node but this doesn't change anything.

So how can I remove the format, when the text stays selected?

```js
document.getElementById('bold').addEventListener('click', () => edit('STRONG'));
document.getElementById('italic').addEventListener('click', () => edit('EM'));

function edit(format) {
  const parentElementOfSelectedText = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentElement;

  // If element is already formatted, undo the format
  if (parentElementOfSelectedText.tagName === format) {
    let grandParentOfSelectedText = parentElementOfSelectedText.parentElement;
    if (parentElementOfSelectedText.textContent) {
      const selectedText = document.createTextNode(parentElementOfSelectedText.textContent);
      grandParentOfSelectedText.insertBefore(selectedText, parentElementOfSelectedText);
      grandParentOfSelectedText.removeChild(parentElementOfSelectedText);
      grandParentOfSelectedText.normalize();
    }
  } else {

    const selectedText = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const node = document.createElement(format);
    const fragment = selectedText.extractContents();

    if (fragment) {
      node.appendChild(fragment);
    }
    selectedText.insertNode(node);
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="bold">B</button>
<button id="italic">I</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: You could treat it like an "undo" function and keep a running memory stored as a variable of the last change made (or an array of changes), then reference that instead of what is highlighted.

Comment: @Lucretius and how do I know when the "undo" function should be invoked?

Comment: I'm actually still picking at this.  Problem seems to be that `parentElementOfSelectedText` navigates up the dom to the `body` tag after formatting is applied.  I'm trying a few different things.  1) selecting the proper range after the formatting is applied so it doesn't "get lost" like its doing.  2) string comparison to see if what is currently selected is the same as what was previously selected.  Probably not the better of the two possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume, that it probably doesn't work, because I am inserting an element inside the parent element. So at this moment, this element is not selected.

correct. but you can just re-select it in js too.

```js
document.getElementById('bold').addEventListener('click', () => edit('STRONG'));
document.getElementById('italic').addEventListener('click', () => edit('EM'));

function edit(format) {
  let parentElementOfSelectedText = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
  
  // If element is already formatted, undo the format
  if (parentElementOfSelectedText.tagName === format || parentElementOfSelectedText.parentElement.tagName === format) {
  if(parentElementOfSelectedText.tagName !== format) parentElementOfSelectedText = parentElementOfSelectedText.parentElement;

    let grandParentOfSelectedText = parentElementOfSelectedText.parentElement;
    if (parentElementOfSelectedText.textContent) {
      const selectedText = document.createTextNode(parentElementOfSelectedText.textContent);

      //work with range of old element because 
      //text nodes are pass by value
      //and we cant create a range after its a text node
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(parentElementOfSelectedText);

      //this replaces some of your code but uses a range
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(selectedText);

      grandParentOfSelectedText.normalize();

      //select the range again :)
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  } else {
    let selectedText = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const node = document.createElement(format);
    const fragment = selectedText.extractContents();

    if (fragment) {
      node.appendChild(fragment);
    }
    selectedText.insertNode(node);


    //make only the inside of the node a range
    //so [...].commonAncestorContainer is "STRONG" or "EM"
    //and gets recognized
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(node);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="bold">B</button>
  <button id="italic">I</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
```

**edits:** adding comments to code; debugging

Comment: Thank you, but there is a bug in your code. Select a text and click on a button. Then unselect the text and select the same again. Now click again on the same button. You will only be able to remove the format when you click on the button multiple times.

Comment: Now it works great. Thank you so much!! Unfortunately, there is another bug related to this topic. Please see my next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72850631/remove-the-format-of-selected-text-only