# Remove the format of selected text only

Tags: javascript

My problem is when I want to remove the format of a selected text, the format of the whole text will be removed.

```js
document.getElementById('bold').addEventListener('click', () => edit('STRONG'));
document.getElementById('italic').addEventListener('click', () => edit('EM'));

function edit(format) {
  let parentElementOfSelectedText = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;

  // If element is already formatted, undo the format
  if (parentElementOfSelectedText.tagName === format || parentElementOfSelectedText.parentElement.tagName === format) {
    if (parentElementOfSelectedText.tagName !== format) parentElementOfSelectedText = parentElementOfSelectedText.parentElement;

    let grandParentOfSelectedText = parentElementOfSelectedText.parentElement;
    if (parentElementOfSelectedText.textContent) {
      const selectedText = document.createTextNode(parentElementOfSelectedText.textContent);
      // const selectedText = document.createTextNode(document.getSelection().toString());

      //work with range of old element because 
      //text nodes are pass by value
      //and we cant create a range after its a text node
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(parentElementOfSelectedText);

      //this replaces some of your code but uses a range
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(selectedText);

      grandParentOfSelectedText.normalize();

      //select the range again :)
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  } else {
    let selectedText = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const node = document.createElement(format);
    const fragment = selectedText.extractContents();

    if (fragment) {
      node.appendChild(fragment);
    }
    selectedText.insertNode(node);


    //make only the inside of the node a range
    //so [...].commonAncestorContainer is "STRONG" or "EM"
    //and gets recognized
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(node);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="bold">B</button>
<button id="italic">I</button>
<div contentEditable="true">Lorem</div>
```

Select *Lorem* and click on the *B* button. So *Lorem* will be bold. Now type *ipsum* after *Lorem*. *Ipsum* will also be bold. Select *ipsum* and click again on the *B* button. Now not only *ipsum* lost its format but also *Lorem*.

It is fine when the text that gets entered will have the same format as the text before. But the user should be able to remove the format of the selected text only.

So when they start to type, the value should be **Lorem ipsum** and when the remove the format of *ipsum*, it should be **Lorem** ipsum.

How can I do this?

---

I also tried it with

```js
const selectedText = document.createTextNode(document.getSelection().toString());
```

but then the unselected text will be removed. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr4jfzvu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the text selection, and keep track of what style was applied previously (bold/italic). If the style has already been applied, remove the style only from the selected text.

```js
document.getElementById('bold').addEventListener('click', () => edit('STRONG'));
document.getElementById('italic').addEventListener('click', () => edit('EM'));

// Variables to track what style has been applied
let textBold = false;
let textItalic = false;

function edit(format) {
  // Getting selected text
  let selectedText = getSelection();
  
  // Create new element
  let el = document.createElement('span');
  
  // Applying style depending on the format
  if (format === 'STRONG') {
    // Assignation to retain previous style
    el.style.fontStyle = (textItalic? 'italic' : 'normal');
    if (textBold === false) {
      el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      textBold = true;
    } else {
      el.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      textBold = false;
    }     
  }

  else if (format === 'EM') {
    // Assignation to retain previous style
    el.style.fontWeight = (textBold ? 'bold' : 'normal');
    if (textItalic === false) {
      el.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
      textItalic = true;
    } else {
      el.style.fontStyle = 'normal';
      textItalic = false;
    }
  }

  el.innerHTML = selectedText.toString();
  let range = selectedText.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
  range.insertNode(el);

}
```

```html
<button id="bold">B</button>
<button id="italic">I</button>
<div contentEditable="true">Lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.getSelection()` returns an object that you are trying to then run functions that return undefined.

You should therefore get the actual string of the selected text to work with.

`window.getSelection().toString();`

Comment: This is how I tried it with `toString()`: https://jsfiddle.net/mr4jfzvu/ ... but still not working as expected.

Comment: I ran this part in my console and it doesn't work so your code just needs to be re thought i think: `const selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);`